# Generating a random letter and drawing that letter in draw.String

Tags: java

In my code I need to generate a random letter from the alphabet. After I generate the letter I need to use the draw.String method to draw the letter. I thought I could use the method charAt(random) to generate the character but it isn't working. My code is below in java. Please let me know what i'm doing wrong and how to fix it. Thanks

```
Random rand = new Random();
String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
String randomLetter = charAt(rand);

Font letterFont = new Font( "SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 94 );
g.setFont( letterFont );
g.drawString( letter , x+45, y+100 );
```

Comment: The compiler will tell you exactly what you're doing wrong -- critically read and *believe* the error message (hint: that's not how you use a Random object).

Comment: hint 2: charAt must be called on something.

Answer (score 1):

I saw two problems with your code.  First, you should bound the range of random numbers you generate to the addressable size of the alphabet string.  Second, the `charAt()` method should be called on the alphabet string, not as a standalone method.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int pos = rand.nextInt(alphabet.length);
String randomLetter = "" + alphabet.charAt(pos);
```

Comment: so the length of my string would be 26. Right?
In your piece of code you have rand.nextInt(alphabet.length);
what is the length. Is it a variable?

Comment: `alphabet.length` returns the length of the alphabet string, which in this case is 26, but you don't even need to worry about that.  We could change the string to something else down the road without the need to change our logic.

Comment: i got it. I was missing a parenthesis. Thanks